# WinAPI, get selected/active window on mouse left down?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Situation: I'm trying to use GetForeground() in Windows Function to get the current foreground Window.

Issue: However the foreground window isn't updated on the OS until LEFT MOUSE UP is sent but I need to get it on the LEFT MOUSE DOWN. I would assume it's the new foreground Window, because when I MOUSE DOWN it's selected and I can move the window around but that's not the case. I can't seem to find any other methods in the Windows Function that I could use to get the currently active window. I tried GetActiveWindow() but the handle is always 0.

Comment: What issue are you really trying to solve? Maybe calling `GetForegroundWindow` is the wrong solution altogether.

Comment: I would like to get the handle of the window I'm actively using. For example, I would mouse left down on a File Explorer (Title bar) on windows, that window is now selected and I can move it around. However I cannot get the handle ID for it. I would assume when I mouse left down windows will have it set as the new Foreground window so by called GetForeground() I would get the handle. but I don't.

Comment: You just repeated your question, but didn't answer, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish. Why do you think you need to know the foreground window on a left mouse button down event? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: Oh Sorry I thought I wasn't clear in my first post. Basically I want to get the info regarding it's position. Which I can by using GetWindowRect, I just missing the hWnd

Comment: Subscribe to winevents or UI Automation events. They will tell you when the current active window has changed.

Comment: You keep weaseling around answering the question: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I simply want to get the position of the WindowPosition (x and y) to display to me? Sorry I'm not sure what you are trying to get at. It's just a learning exercise, there is no "real objective" other than exploring the Window Functions.

Comment: @MichaelChiLam Based on your response to my answer, it seems that what you're trying to do (which is what IInspectable is asking) is to retrieve a window from a screen coordinate. Note that it is not directly related to the active/foreground window. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the HWND from a mouse coordinate, you should look into [WindowFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558.aspx).

(Perhaps also see: 
[What's the difference between WindowFromPhysicalPoint and WindowFromPoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324954/whats-the-difference-between-windowfromphysicalpoint-and-windowfrompoint))